# Which point is more northerly?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got two latlng's in google maps. One is a northeast part of a bounds and one is a southwest part of a bounds - the problem is, I don't know which is which and they don't always have to be in the same order, i.e. sometimes the first point is the northeast, sometimes the second point is the northeast.

What I want to know is, given 2 latlng coordinates, is there anyway that I can tell which one is the more northerly latlng?

Comment: just checking its value won't tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latitude component of a coordinate measures the north/south location.  If the latitude component is greater, then it will always be more to the north.  Negative latitudes refer to locations south of the equator, so the same principal applies.  (-90 is less than -60, and it is farther south.)

See: http://www.mrdowling.com/601-grid.html